# IMAP Search with " character

Tags: c#, imap

SEARCH TEXT "Joe says: "i want to search" and exits."

how can i search this text with IMAP SEARCH

this doesn't work : "Joe says: \"i want to search\" and exits."

Answer (score 1):

searching in IMAP using C# is shown in our [Rebex IMAP tutorial](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/tutorial-imap.aspx#searching).

```
// create client, connect and log in  
Imap client = new Imap();
client.Connect("server");
client.Login("username", "password");

// select the folder for search operation  
client.SelectFolder("Inbox");

ImapMessageCollection fromJoe = client.Search
(
  ImapSearchParameter.Body("Joe says: \"i want to search\" and exists.");
);
```

The component takes care of correct escaping automatically.

If you are curious how it is escaped try producing a log as shown at [rebex.net/kb/logging.aspx](http://www.rebex.net/kb/logging.aspx) and check the IMAP commands and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say *how* you're searching IMAP, I can't give you a definitive answer, but could it be that you have to double-escape the quotation marks? Once for C# and once for the IMAP search?

```
string searchString = "Joe says: \\\"i want to search\\\" and exits.";
```

Answer (score -1):

IMAP search does not support arbitrary string -- so no, there is no way to do this.

Comment: OK maybe. IMAP SEARCH with REGEX? and how to? any source?